# Processing large files using Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Goal: Read a text file line by line using multithreading

Solution:

```
import threading
import queue

#Configure the number of threads
n_thread = 5
#Create the queue
queue = queue.Queue()

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    #Assign thread working with queue
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            host = self.queue.get()  #Get from queue job
            print (self.getName() + ":" + host)
            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

    #Create number process
    for i in range(n_thread):
        t = ThreadClass(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        #Start thread
        t.start()

    hostfile = open("C:\\Users\\rparpani\Desktop\\Powershell\\GAP\\gap_reference_product_dump.txt","r")
    for line in hostfile:
        #Put line to queue
        queue.put(line)
        #wait on the queue until everything has been processed
        queue.join()
```

Problem: NameError: name 'ThreadClass' is not defined. Not sure why I get this error while running my script whereas i did define threadclass. Can someone please suggest me on how to resolve this

Comment: Everything at `#Create number process` on down should be dedented. Right now its part of the class definition. In the class definition, the class has not yet been bound to "ThreadClass".

Comment: Thank you. That resolved it and now see each thread reading a line

Comment: Adding CPU to a problem whose bottleneck is in I/O might not make anything faster. The overhead of parallelism could easily make it slower by introducing congestion to an already busy I/O channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `#Create number processes` is part of the class definition becuase it is indented. Unindent to get it to work i.e.:

```
import threading
import queue

#Configure the number of threads
n_thread = 5
#Create the queue
queue = queue.Queue()

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    #Assign thread working with queue
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            host = self.queue.get()  #Get from queue job
            print (self.getName() + ":" + host)
            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()
#Create number process
for i in range(n_thread):
    t = ThreadClass(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    #Start thread
    t.start()

hostfile = open("C:\\Users\\rparpani\Desktop\\Powershell\\GAP\\gap_reference_product_dump.txt","r")
for line in hostfile:
    #Put line to queue
    queue.put(line)
    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed
    queue.join()
```